# Can we pass a parameter to view did load or view will appear of other class from a class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, object, view

Sorry if it is not a standard question, but now your solutions can help me out.  In my app, I have two classes: `ClassA` and `ClassB`.  `ClassB` has a table view in it.  I am using a query to populate the table view in `ClassB`, but the column name through which I have to query is what I get from `ClassA`, which I want to pass to `ClassB` and to perform the query and populate the table view.  Can I pass a parameter to `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`?  These get called when the view loads.  Or is there any other method to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you declare a property for that?

```
@interface ClassB:...

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * columnName

@end
```

and synthesize it in the implementation.

When you are creating `ClassB` instance from `ClassA` then do this,

```
ClassB * classB = [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:.. bundle:..];
classB.columnName = theColumnName;
[self pushViewController:classB animated:YES];
[classB release];
```

Make use of this parameter in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Just be careful. This example does not cater for the use case where you set the property after ClassB's viewDidLoad method gets called. You'll be setting the property, but the changes won't reflect

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you write a setter method for your query. Once Class B is instantiated you can call the method any time to update the data set and the table view.

You'll need to adjust the parameters to handle whatever form of representation you'll be using for your query.

ClassB.h

```
@interface ClassB : UITableViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *query;
```

ClassB.m

```
// method declared in ClassB

@implementation 

@synthesize query;

// other methods here ...

- (void)setQuery:(NSString *)newQuery
{   
    // query is an instance variable declared in your .h
    [newQuery retain];
    [query release];
    query = newQuery;

    // perform your new data fetch with the supplied query

    [self.tableView reload];
}

@end
```

ClassA.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    classB = [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassB" bundle:nil];
    [classB setQuery:@"your query string here"];
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate as i am not having any exprience of doing it.i mean in which class i have to write what

Comment: Use this if your column name changes often during the lifetime of the view controller i.e. `ClassB`.

Comment: I've used this approach myself too, though you need to be careful and aware of side effects, such as setting `self.query = nil` in `-dealloc` and the tableview datasource methods not being prepared for that scenario (lots of stuff possibly not being available).

Answer (score 2):

You normally create a property on the target class and populated it with whatever you need to pass along, then you push the other class onto the stack, or tell it to update.

Comment: please give a small sample as it is hard to understand for a fresher like me that what you are saying

Comment: That's quite basic stuff. Look it up in a book, or find a tutorial online (there must be plenty). The navigation controller based template that Apple provides in Xcode includes some code that illustrates this. (As does @Deepak in his answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You pass the value to your class or object constructor.  You then save the value to a property in that class.  You then access that property from the view did load, or your other events.

This is more a general programming concept, than anything related to objective c, the iPad, etc.

So, in your header file, you define a property.  Then you synthesize that property the c file.  Then you set the property in the constructor.  Then you access the property in your view did load event.