# Reusing a property over multiple files

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have created a property like so

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AFOAuth1Client *twitterClient;
```

however i want the same property to be used over multiple files. Instead of creating multiple versions of the property on different files. I know its a simple question but help is needed!

Comment: Inheritance, one of the most important concept in OO Programming.

Comment: Subclasses and macros?  Not exactly sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to passing it amongst different view controllers I usually suggest one of three methods:

- passing it from view to view (best obj-oriented option)
- creating a singleton of the object to be used globally (sometimes frowned upon)
- instantiate it via your app delegate or via a global variable (ugly & messy)

Comment: I tried passing it View to View like this but it claims that the property does not exist. But I used this and solved my issue:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435193/can-we-pass-a-parameter-to-view-did-load-or-view-will-appear-of-other-class-from

Comment: That will certainly work if you're programmatically pushing your next view controller. If you ever navigate back to the original view controller make sure you give yourself some breadcrumbs ;)